# java simple json fetch data from database and display

Tags: java, json

i would like to ask on how to produce the desire json output like below:

```
{
 "Result":"OK",
 "Records":[
  {"PersonId":1,"Name":"Benjamin Button","Age":17,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
  {"PersonId":2,"Name":"Douglas Adams","Age":42,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
  {"PersonId":3,"Name":"Isaac Asimov","Age":26,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
  {"PersonId":4,"Name":"Thomas More","Age":65,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"}
 ]
}
```

my jsp code are look like below:

```
<%@page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.parser.ParseException"%>
<%
    String dept = (String)request.getParameter("dept");
    String sql  = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE department='"+dept+"'";

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn=null;
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/jspjsons","root","123456");
        ResultSet rs=null;
        Statement stm1=conn.createStatement();

        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        rs=stm1.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
            obj.put("PersonId", rs.getString("id"));
            obj.put("Name", rs.getString("name"));
            obj.put("Age", rs.getString("age"));
            obj.put("RecordDate", rs.getString("date"));

            list.add(obj);
        }

        out.print(list);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        out.println("<h1>"+ex+"</g1>");
    }
%>
```

also upon display the output there is always the front and back bracket like this [], how do i get rid of it? need it to start and end with {} not []

Comment: Your code means you want array of objects, Because of that it must start with [].

Comment: how to get it start and end with {} ? like the desired output above

Comment: Then you don't need JSONArray list = new JSONArray(); directly Instead you need JSONObject  inside it you can define JSONArray property and fil l it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the `Records` array correctly (which you have stored in the `list` variable), all you would need to do is add that to a new `JSONObject` along with the `Result`.

Keep in mind that `{ ... }` indicates a `JSONObject`, and `[ ... ]` indicates a `JSONArray`.

```
while(rs.next())
{
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    obj.put("PersonId", rs.getString("id"));
    obj.put("Name", rs.getString("name"));
    obj.put("Age", rs.getString("age"));
    obj.put("RecordDate", rs.getString("date"));

    list.add(obj);
}

//Include this code beneath to create the JSON you require (mainObject).
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
mainObject.put("Result", "OK");
mainObject.put("Records", list);
```

Comment: you mean to use JSONObject instead of JSONArray like out.print(mainObject); correct?

Comment: Yes, `mainObject` should look like the desired JSON you have included at the top of your question.